# How to select and then split data then select the second data?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

So I am selecting TOP 60 data, then what I want is to remove the first 30 data to get the 31st. But I am struggling to find any solution to this. Here is my code:

```
    SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 60  Name, Signature 
    FROM TBL_Attendance WHERE Status = '" + lblStat.Text + "' AND Date = '" + 
    this.dtSelectDate.Text + "' ", conn);
```

That is the query that I want to edit to get the 31st data.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Look into adding RowNumber:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017   Then you can use this as subquery and just select the row numbers you want (so where RowNumber = 31).

Comment: So basically you only want the data starting from 31st id?

Comment: You are going to get random results each time.  You must use an orderby with SQL Server to get same results each time.  SQL uses multiple thread when doing a search and the order will be random.

Comment: I want to select the 31st value not id because i am using this to generate report

Comment: Could you just read the 31st row from the datatable?

Comment: You have no `ORDER BY`.  `TOP` with no `ORDER BY` returns indeterminate rows.  You might as well select any 30 if you want 30.

Comment: Can i use EXCEPT? To get the 31st data.

Comment: @DietherNoche If it had an order by, you could SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT TOP 31 .... ORDER BY x DESC) ORDER BY x ASC - or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. i just change the image to varbinary for to be compared

```
     SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Name, Signature FROM 
     TBL_Attendance WHERE Status = '" + lblStat.Text + "' AND Date = '" + 
     this.dtSelectDate.Text + "' EXCEPT SELECT TOP 30 Name, Signature FROM 
     TBL_Attendance  WHERE Status = '" + lblStat.Text + "' AND Date = '" + 
     this.dtSelectDate.Text + "' ", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your SQL database you might want to look at this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/compact/sql-server-compact-4.0/gg699618(v=sql.110)

*this only works for Microsoft SQL DB 2012 >

It works like pagination.

Comment: I am using an Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Try like suggested here: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/219741/Select-nth-row-of-a-table-in-sql-server

```
WITH whateverhere AS (
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TBL_Attendance.Name)) as row,*
    FROM TBL_Attendance)
SELECT * FROM whateverhere WHERE row > 31
```

Comment: It is giving me error the row column is not found. I am using this query to select values for my data set and put it into my RDLC Report.

Comment: Can you try to run this quuery in your SQL server? See if you still get that error.